# Is the output of R quantile function "inclusive"?

Tags: r, quantile

I've got a vector (which I've called `x1`) of random observations from a binomial distribution with mean 55 and p = 47/55.

When I run `quantile(x1, c(0.025, 0.975))`, the output is:

`2.5% 97.5%`
`42   52`

My question is whether the interval which covers 95% of my generated values is `[42, 52]` or `(42, 52)`. I've searched all over, but have found nothing.

Comment: Did you check out the `?quantile` help page? The function supports many different ways to calculate quanties. The default type probably isn't appropriate for discrete distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is exclusive by default.

This is pretty easy to check:

```
quantile(1:1000, c(0.025, 0.975))
```

Returns

```
2.5%   97.5% 
25.975 975.025
```

So R is returning `(25.975, 975.025)`, which corresponds on this set to `[26, 975]`

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is, the default ouput of "qualite" function is exlusive.